# Atma's state after death

Tags: scripture, belief

It is said that once a  person is dead the atma exits from the body. Will this atma be given to same person born in different form as per karma like animal or bird or it will be given to some other. May be that person will be a bad soul but this atma may be a punya one. Anything mentioned in scriptures in Hindu mythology?

Comment: That is not Atma but Jivatama i.e, it has Subtle body. Subtle body wears Physical body (Annamaya Kosha) later according to Karma.

Comment: Understand the question-I know what you have told  physical wear etc is that atma will be given to some other creatures or bird or person? Normally I ask critics question only. You said u r 22 but I am 50  my thinking is more experienced than you--understand, analyse and answer if you can provide the right one. Frankly I poured thru words.

Comment: First, you should read properly what i said. I said difference between Atma and Jivatma. Second, no one can tell you exactly what form that Jivatma will take birth, even scriptures.  You used **Atma for Jivatma**. How did our ages matter here?

Comment: you read half scriptures and answer in a half baked way.If you do not know do not say no one can say. It nmight have been mentioned in some puranas--refer garuda purana-- go deeper if you can understand u will come to know the answer. That is why I told age matters. You will spill instantaneously  many a circumstances I have seen. Only scriptures u will refer and put in comment. You will not analyse at all. answers are vague.

Comment: I read Garuda Purana. indeed, it's simple that Jivatma will take birth based on Karma and we (normal human beings) do not know its karma. Even Garuda Purana says the same and we go to heaven or hell depending on it. So, what can anyone say about its next life? We need to analyze various cases. But these things are already answered on this site. It looks like you feel inferior when someone younger than you say something. This is what most of Indian elders feel. Not all elders are always correct and same time not all youngsters are correct.

Comment: You might have read a small book on Garuda purana. That is why you are not able to tell the answer. Being a book worm and answering the question will not suit anything. Go deeper, analyse and proceed. I am not telling in ahankara  I have read Thiruvaimozhi more than 10 times but cud understand meaning to some extent only. It is the extract of vedas. Just go thru that and let me know.